# Зачем в обработке запросов на nginx указываются "лишние" методы?

Tags: nginx, cors

В попытках разобраться с настройках CORS, я облазил большое количество ресурсов и форумов.
Решение было найдено и понято. Кроме одного момента.
Для чего указывать add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'; в каждом $request_method?

```
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Set-Cookie,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 108000;
        return 204;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Set-Cookie,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization' always;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Set-Cookie,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization' always;
    }
```

Comment: Судя по документации, это просто любители копипасты. Этот заголовок имеет смысл только в ответе на `OPTIONS`.

Comment: Ещё `Set-Cookie` тоже бессмыленная фигня